# Namespace route with regex in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, routes

I'm using namespaces to make an api in rails. In my system, I need to make an optional rule in regex that my nginx will run in a different way.

I have this in `routes.rb`

```
namespace 'api', constraints: { format: 'json' } do
  namespace :v1 do
    # ....
  end
end
```

Request example: `/api/v1/posts/new`

I need to make an optional query in `routes.rb` beginning with `/_sh/`.

Example:

```
/api/v1/posts/new
/_sh/api/v1/posts/new => # Same response, controller and action
```

How can I do this?

I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope `_sh` can be denoted by parentheses. Path part `_sh/` becomes optional.

```
scope '(_sh)' do
  namespace 'api', constraints: { format: 'json' } do
    namespace :v1 do
      # ....
    end
  end
end
```

You can use the `:constraints` option to enforce a format for a optional segment:

```
scope '(:optional_prefix)', constraints: {optional_prefix: /_sh/} do
  namespace 'api', constraints: { format: 'json' } do
    namespace :v1 do
      # ....
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an scope for this, I'm not sure is this answer your question bu I did something similar in this way

```
scope ":name_of_param", name_of_param: /regex_to_match/ do
  namespace 'api'
   namespace 'v1'
   end
  end
end
```